# Output of SQL query is not coming properly (multiple Lines for status)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sccm

Below is the query I have written to fetch the patch compliance status.

```
 select 
vUI.Title As 'Title',
vui.ArticleID, 
CASE 
    WHEN vsn.StateID = 0 or vsn.StateID = 1 or vsn.StateID =  2 THEN --'No Status'
    count(vRSV.Netbios_Name0) 
END As 'No Status',
CASE
    WHEN vsn.StateID = 3 or vsn.StateID = 4 or vsn.StateID = 5 or vsn.StateID = 7 or vsn.StateID = 8 or vsn.StateID = 12 or vsn.StateID = 14 THEN --'In Progress'
    count(vRSV.Netbios_Name0) 
end as 'In Progress',
Case
    WHEN vsn.StateID = 6 or vsn.StateID = 11 or vsn.StateID = 14 THEN --'Failed'
    count(vRSV.Netbios_Name0) 
End as 'Failed',
Case
    WHEN vsn.StateID = 9 or vsn.StateID = 10 THEN --'Success'
    count(vRSV.Netbios_Name0) 
    --ELSE 'Not Installed'
END As Success
from v_UpdateComplianceStatus vUCS
join v_UpdateInfo vUI
  on vUCS.CI_ID=vUI.CI_ID
  join v_R_System_Valid vRSV  on vUCS.ResourceId=vRSV.resourceid
inner join v_FullCollectionMembership_Valid vFCMV
  on vUCS.ResourceId=vFCMV.ResourceID
  and vFCMV.CollectionID='CB00123' 
join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM vGOS
    on vUCS.ResourceID = vGOS.ResourceID
join v_StateNames vSN
  on vUCS.LastEnforcementMessageID = vSN.StateID and (vSN.TopicType=402 or vSN.TopicType=500 or vSN.TopicType=400)
where vui.DateLastModified between '2019-09-12' and '2019-10-12'
  group by vUI.Title,vui.ArticleID, vsn.StateID
```

I was expecting output like below.

```
ArticleID   No Status   In Progress Failed  Success
4516033     NULL          8           102   2149
```

But output is coming as below.

```
ArticleID   No Status   In Progress Failed  Success
4516033     NULL          NULL        25    NULL
4516033     NULL          NULL        NULL  253
4516033     NULL          NULL       NULL   1896
4516033     NULL          NULL        69    NULL
4516033     NULL           8           8    NULL
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: More rows than expected is probably a `GROUP BY` problem. Make sure to include the grouped columns on your output and you will see why they aren't being grouped as you expect. Other than that, you will have to supply example data to really see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try summing each value and not suing count() on each row

```
select 
vUI.Title As 'Title',
vui.ArticleID, 
sum ( CASE 
      WHEN vsn.StateID = 0 
        or vsn.StateID = 1 or vsn.StateID =  2 THEN  1 else 0 
      END  ) As 'No Status',

sum ( case 
      WHEN vsn.StateID = 3 or vsn.StateID = 4 or vsn.StateID = 5 
              or vsn.StateID = 7 or vsn.StateID = 8 
               or vsn.StateID = 12 or vsn.StateID = 14 THEN 1 else 0 

       end ) as 'In Progress',

 sum( CASE  
      WHEN vsn.StateID = 6 or vsn.StateID = 11
          or vsn.StateID = 14 
     THEN 1 else 0 

     End ) as 'Failed',
   sum( CASE WHEN vsn.StateID = 9 or vsn.StateID = 10 
      THEN 1 else 0
     END ) As Success
from v_UpdateComplianceStatus vUCS
join v_UpdateInfo vUI
  on vUCS.CI_ID=vUI.CI_ID
  join v_R_System_Valid vRSV  on vUCS.ResourceId=vRSV.resourceid
inner join v_FullCollectionMembership_Valid vFCMV
  on vUCS.ResourceId=vFCMV.ResourceID
  and vFCMV.CollectionID='CB00123' 
join v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM vGOS
    on vUCS.ResourceID = vGOS.ResourceID
join v_StateNames vSN
  on vUCS.LastEnforcementMessageID = vSN.StateID and (vSN.TopicType=402 or vSN.TopicType=500 or vSN.TopicType=400)
where vui.DateLastModified between '2019-09-12' and '2019-10-12'
  group by vUI.Title,vui.ArticleID
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Let me try. I tried your query but data is same.

Comment: @Ironic  .. asnwer  updated  .. you have a (wrong)  vsn.StateID  in group by ...  you need  remove ..

Comment: Thanks. It worked. You are life saver. I wish i would have that much of knowledge.

Comment: @Ironic   .thank you but what I know I only learned a little at a time ...

Comment: @scaoisEdge Have raised another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641801/sql-sum-values-of-two-columns-row you can help if you are free.

Answer (score 2):

You want conditional aggregation.  The `CASE` is the argument to the aggregation function.  So:

```
select vUI.Title As Title, vui.ArticleID, 
       sum(case when vsn.StateID in (0, 1, 2)
                then 1 else 0 
           end) as no_status,
       sum(case when vsn.StateID in (3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 12, 14)
                then 1 else 0 
           end) as in_progress,
       . . . 
from . . .
group by vUI.Title As Title, vui.ArticleID;
```

Note that you need to change *both* the `SELECT` and the `GROUP BY`.

Also:

- Do not use single quotes for column aliases.  That just causes confusion.  Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.
- Choose column aliases that do not need to be escaped (so avoid spaces).
- `IN` simplifies your comparisons.

Comment: @Ironic . . . As the OP you can choose whatever answer you like.  But, I can ask why.  This was the first answer (by over 2 minutes) and seems like simpler SQL to me.  Is there a reason you prefer the other answer?