# Sum values of two columns row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is the query I have prepared to fetch the details from the database.

```
select vUI.ArticleID , vUCS.NumInstalled,vUCS.NumPresent, vUCS.NumPending, vUCS.NumFailed, vUCS.NumNotApplicable , vUCS.NumMissing, vUCS.NumUnknown , vUCS.NumTotal
from v_Update_DeploymentSummary_Live vUCS 
inner join v_UpdateInfo vUI
    on vUCS.CI_ID=vUI.CI_ID
where vUCS.CollectionID='RA00686' --or  vUCS.CollectionID='RA00785'
```

There are a couple of things I tried to achieve but getting hard time.

Below is the output data.

[image]

I am hoping that screenshot should be visible. but in case if its missing I would like to add values of **vUCS.NumInstalled and vUCS.NumPresent** as both are showing data for success.

How can I add the value of two columns in a row?

My query is little bit slow due to **vUCS.CollectionID='RA00686' or  vUCS.CollectionID='RA00785'**, I am trying to change it as it is taking more than 3 minutes to run.

**Current Output**

```
ArticleID   NumInstalled    NumPresent  NumPending
4484107         2               16           2
4519998         0              0             0
4521860        7573           7738          13
```

**Expected Output**

```
ArticleID   NumInstalled    NumPending
4484107         18            2
4519998         0             0
4521860        15311          13
```

Comment: Sample data would be a bit help.  Your question is not clear.  Also, are you asking about performance or how to add columns.

Comment: Output is added as screenshot. ARe you able to see this?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You mention that you have "tried a couple of things", can you elaborate on that? What have you tried, and what were the results of those attempts?

Comment: Updated the question with expected output.

Comment: It would be helpful as well to know the definition of the columns that you want to add together. Are the both defined as a numeric type, varchar type, can either or both be null?

Comment: this is mean you want to sum NumInstalled    NumPresent   in one column?

Comment: @gmiley This data is coming from SCCM database and i was trying to get this data from last one week. I created almost 200 queries to get this data due to lack of infromation about the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
select vUI.ArticleID , 
    ISNULL(vUCS.NumInstalled,0)+ISNULL(vUCS.NumPresent,0) AS NumInstalled,
    vUCS.NumPending
from v_Update_DeploymentSummary_Live vUCS 
inner join v_UpdateInfo vUI
    on vUCS.CI_ID=vUI.CI_ID
where vUCS.CollectionID='RA00686'
```

And you have to create an `Index` for the `vUCS.CollectionID` column to increase the query performance.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCX_v_Update_DeploymentSummary_Live_Indx1 ON v_Update_DeploymentSummary_Live(CollectionID)
```

Comment: Thanks For your help Dinesh. I will test and let you know. Voted Up.